# change the colour of DatePicker [Xamarin.Forms]

Tags: xamarin, datepicker, xamarin.forms, background-color

is there any way to change the background colour of the DatePicker control while showing a calendar view?
Please check the attached screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Add the following to your style.xml file:

```
<item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>

<style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorAccent">#2196F3</item>
</style>
```

Complete XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
</style>
<!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
<style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette-->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#2196F3</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
     which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#2196F3</item>
    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
     colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#2196F3</item>
</style>
<style name="MyDatePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:headerBackground">#2196F3</item>
</style>
<style name="MyDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePickerStyle</item>
</style>
```

**UPDATE**

For the timepicker:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="android:timePickerDialogTheme">@style/TimePickerDialogTheme</item>
```

Then set the timePickerDialogTheme and set the timePickerStyle:

```
<style name="TimePickerDialogTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
<item name="colorAccent">#ff6d3024</item>
<item name="android:timePickerStyle">@style/TimePickerDialogStyle</item>
```

Now you can create the style.xml:

```
<style name="TimePickerDialogStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.TimePicker">
<item name="colorAccent">#ff6d3024</item>
<item name="android:timePickerMode">clock</item>
<item name="android:headerBackground">#ff6d3024</item>
<item name="android:headerTimeTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.TimePickerDialogStyle.TimeLabel</item> <!-- TimePicker Time *TextAppearance* -->
<item name="android:numbersTextColor">#ff000000</item>
<item name="android:numbersSelectorColor">#ff6d3024</item>
<item name="android:numbersBackgroundColor">#ffdddddd</item>
```

Comment: Thank Svekke, It's working can you please let me know how to change the colour of Time Picker, I have tried to Replace Date with Time but not working. and Also, the textbox border colour.

Comment: This is great for static styles and works as expected, but im my Xamarin.Forms app i have added the ability to change themes. how would you go about setting these Date and Time picker colors dynamically?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Though the update feels a bit unnecessary in my opinion. more confusing than anything really