# Change Color in DatePicker

Tags: xamarin.forms

When I try to create a `DatePicker` it appears all white, and only the selected date is black which I changed through the `Textcolor` property. The rest of the graphics appear fuchsia in my case. How can I change the rest?[image: My DataPicker]

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41761197/change-the-colour-of-datepicker-xamarin-forms?

Comment: I get the following error entering the indicated string in that answer.
`Error <item> must have a 'type' attribute.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9033) in Forms with Dark Theme.

There was a [workaround](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9033#issuecomment-762781496) posted recently

> This is a super-ugly hack, but it solved the problem for me. Based on what @stefanbogaard86 suggested, I tried using Visual="Material", but the problem I ran into was that the DatePicker entry box didn't match the rest of the form. But, he's right that using Material did fix the issue with the picker rendering. So, I found this to get the best of both visuals:
>
> ```xml
> <AbsoluteLayout>
>   <DatePicker
>       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
>       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
>       Date="{Binding Birthdate}"
>       Format="yyyy-MM-dd"
>       Style="{DynamicResource DatePicker}" />
>   <DatePicker
>       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
>       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
>       Date="{Binding Birthdate}"
>       Format="yyyy-MM-dd"
>       Opacity="0"
>       Style="{DynamicResource DatePicker}"
>       Visual="Material" />
> </AbsoluteLayout>
> ```
>
> The first picker is what we want to show in the form. The second one is what we want to be clickable and show the full date picker, but we don't it shown in the form, so its opacity is zero. They're both bound to the same property, so when you change the value they both work.
>
> Like I said, this is super-ugly, but it works.