# Xamarin.Forms DatePickerCustomRenderer doesn't recognize the IOnDateSetListener

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I tried to adapt a TimePicker Custom Renderer to a DatePicker. Long Story Short it is not working as expected, it says that the Keyword this can't be converted from Dialog to OnDateSetListener, so i tried to add a explicit conversion: (DatePickerDialog.IOnDateSetListener)this. But also i can't get it running.

The TimePicker went well, there i had it from here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67556936/howto-change-style-and-colours-of-timepickers)

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker), typeof(DatePickerDialogCustomRenderer))]

namespace Arbeitszeitrechner_Forms.Droid
{
    class DatePickerDialogCustomRenderer : DatePickerRenderer
    {
        private readonly Context _context;
        public DatePickerDialogCustomRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            _context = context;

        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
        }

        DatePickerDialog dialog;
        protected override DatePickerDialog CreateDatePickerDialog(int year, int month, int day)
        {
            dialog = new DatePickerDialog(_context, Resource.Style.DatePickerTheme, (DatePickerDialog.IOnDateSetListener)this, year, month, day);

            return dialog;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to implement IOnDateSetListener

Comment: and how do i do that?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/pickers/date-picker

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/implement-interface?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description and code, you want to change DatePicker dialog color by custom render, I think you need to inherit **MaterialDatePickerRenderer** for **DatePickerDialogCustomRenderer**.I use the following code, it works fine.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker), typeof(DatePickerDialogCustomRenderer))]
namespace FormsSample.Droid
{
class DatePickerDialogCustomRenderer : MaterialDatePickerRenderer
{
    private readonly Context _context;
    public DatePickerDialogCustomRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        _context = context;

    }
  
    protected override DatePickerDialog CreateDatePickerDialog(int year, int month, int day)
    {
        Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker view = Element;
       
        var dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Context, Resource.Style.TimePickerTheme, (o, e) =>
         {
             view.Date = e.Date;
             ((IElementController)view).SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedPropertyKey, false);           
         }, year, month, day);

        return dialog;

    }
}
}
```

The screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Sounds intresting... but my Visual Studio doesn't find any Namespace or Type called MaterialDatePickerRenderer

Comment: @Chessmate try to download `Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material` by nuget package.